# pytest failing in AWS SAM project due to ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-module

I have an AWS SAM project with the following folder structure:

```
account/
   __init__.py
   layers/
       __init__.py
       config/
           settings.py
       utils/
           logger.py
   get_accounts/
       app.py
       requirements.txt
   tests/
        requirements.txt
        integration/
            test_api_gateway.py
        unit/
            test_handler.py
```

When I run `python3 -m pytest tests/unit/` from the project root directory, I get the following error:

> ImportError while importing test module
> '/Users/johnsmith/dev/myproject/account/tests/unit/test_handler.py'. Hint:
> make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

> Traceback:
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py:127:
> in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) tests/unit/test_handler.py:3: in 
> from get_accounts import app get_accounts/app.py:14: in 
> from layers.utils.logger import get_logger layers/utils/logger.py:1: in 
> from config.settings import ApplicationConfig E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

The issue is when the test file imports the main application, main application has dependencies that lie in "layers" folder; For some reason, it's not able to import those files. When I start the application using `sam local` command, it works, but it fails when I run pytest.

I've tried

- adding `__init__.py` to all folders under "layers" folder.
- Creating a setup.py and specifying "config" as the package name, then running `pip install -e .` [based on pytest's documentation](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-as-part-of-application-code)
- In `get_accounts/app.py`, specifying "layers" before `config.settings` and `utils.logger` when importing those items
- Removing `__init__.py` from test folder

These were all possible solutions mentioned from stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.

Here's how the imports in `get_accounts/app.py` look like:

```
import json
import requests
from config.settings import ApplicationConfig
from utils.logger import get_logger
from pprint import pprint
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how I can get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce more or less what you are encountering. Here are my files:

```py
account > cat tests/unit/test_import.py 
import get_accounts.app

def test_hello():
    print("Hello World")
account > cat get_accounts/app.py 
from config.settings import ApplicationConfig

account > cat layers/config/settings.py 

class ApplicationConfig:
    pass
```

It raises an error saying config cannot be imported. Changing from:

```py
from config.settings import ApplicationConfig
```

to

```py
from layers.config.settings import ApplicationConfig
```

Solves the problem in my setup.

```
account > python3 -m pytest tests/
===================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/brunno/account
collected 1 item

tests/unit/test_import.py .                                                                                                                              [100%] 

====================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s =======================================================================
```

Comment: Hi bvan, thanks for looking into the problem. I've tried this solution, but it didn't work for me. When I tried adding "layers" in the import statements and build the application, it will actually fail. I'm not fully understanding how this "layers" folder works, but I believe it gets compiled during build time when the project uses a docker image to simulate the AWS API Gateway environment. A better way to simulate this would be to [create a new SAM project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html)

Comment: Have you tried adding on top of the app.py file `sys.path.append("..")` and `sys.path.append("../layers")`?  It seems like SAM is not getting the right path or starting at a different directory than expected.